# how to add and display custom errors in rails2

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a controller action create and before I save a record I am checking one record in database and if it exists it will save.. Otherwise I need to display error as "Record Not Found". Also I have certain validations defined for this model.

```
if @issue.empty?
  @project.save
          format.js {render :action=> 'create'}

        else
          @error = true
          format.html{render :action=> 'new'}
          format.js {render :action=> 'create'}

end
```

How will I add it in the @errors object and display it.. I am rendering errors partial and looping each error msgs...

Comment: Validation based errors you can associate at model level and activeRecordObject.errors will give you the result.  validates_uniqueness_of :name, :message => '%{value} has already been taken'

Comment: So what is the best way to show "Record NOt Found"error msg here...

Comment: So your use case it, update a model with values else throw error. If it fails during updating, object.errors takes care of it. If it does not exist, add an instance variable and add the error message. works?

Answer (score 1):

Validation based errors you can associate at model level and activeRecordObject.errors will give you the result directly.
 `validates_uniqueness_of :name, :message => '%{value} has already been taken'` .

You can use the same view on depending on values of view can render different html too, perhaps less confusing. One view which check if object.errors.present?, then do this else render something else.